# MS Graph - Fetch user profile photo with "profile" consent

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#openid-connect-oidc-scopes), it seems as though I should be able to fetch a users profile photo from MS Graph with the `profile` permission
[image]

I will get a `403` when hitting `me/photo` or `users/{identifier}/photo`. The [photo documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0) shows the least privileged consent is `User.Read`. This is for a work or school account.

Is there an endpoint I can use to get the user profile photo with only the `profile` permission consented, or am I understanding the profile permission incorrectly.

Cheers

Comment: are you using Azure AD B2C tenants ? you can check please check your access token by decoding on  https://jwt.ms/ .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are not using Azure AD B2C tenants ,have you tried by access endpoint to get your profile photo?
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value .

[image]

ref doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0

thanks

Comment: Thanks - If I hit the me/photo endpoint I get a 403. This is a work account. It is standard Azure AD, not B2C. 
Cheers

Comment: Is URL - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value worked for you ?